# Alternative to using the REPL in Clojure for quickly trying out stuff

Tags: clojure

In Python world, whenever I need to try something I'd just make a new file `a.py` and insert the code that I want to try, and run it. This works because of the shebang line 
`#!/usr/bin/env python3`
Which tells the os which interpreter to call for the file.

Is there an equivalent to this in clojure? I don't want to jump through all the hoops of running `lein new app` and specifying the main ns, everytime I just want to check out what a few lines of code does in a file.

Note that I already know about lein repl. And I tried to use that as the shebang
`#!/usr/bin/lein repl`
But this just brings up an error
`No :main namespace specified in
project.clj.`

Comment: Not really what you are looking for, but just to have it mentioned: you can run `lein repl` outside of a project and you can then there run `(load-file "filename.clj")`

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer to take the long route of creating a file and specifying the interpreter instead of running `ipython`?

Comment: @Josh I just rely on my text editor too much. Just more comfortable with being able to move up and down lines and such

Comment: Sending partial content or whole namespaces from the editor into just some running REPL is usually easy too (assuming though you have setup your editor beforehand).  So starting `lein repl` somewhere, connect your editor to that session and just send over forms. I doubt many people use a REPL really as their primary input for code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [Clojure CLI tools installed](https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started), then you can use shebang scripts:

`test.clj`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env clj

(def x 10)
(println "x =" x)
```

In terminal:

```
chmod +x test.clj
./test.clj
```

Output:

`x = 10`

Comment: I get the same error `No :main namespace specified in
project.clj.`

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to do `lein run` instead. It works perfectly

Comment: Prefer `#!/usr/bin/env clojure` in the shebang line. `clj` has an additional layer for interactive use that you don’t need in a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with boot. See https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Scripts

Also, the ClojureVerse has a thread on this at https://clojureverse.org/t/scripting-with-clj/1618/5 where some options are being discussed.

Still, you should be aware that such an approach is probably not very useful. On the one hand you quite often want to manage dependencies on the other there's the startup time of the JVM, in particular when you need to compile some clojure sources first. If you need to run your script a few times because you're trying out thing, the startup time quickly becomes are real obstacle.

As an idea, I usually keep a leiningen project around for quick experiments. Here, I can adjust the dependencies as needed and quickly fire up a REPL to tinker with ideas and try out things. For me, it is not uncommon to find this REPL up and running and an Emacs already connected to it.

Comment: Your idea about an experiment project for only quick experiments is pretty great